# Actionscript 3: Is there a way to re-create the look of a Flash Textarea component using AS3 TextField?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textfield

I would like to know if there is a way to re-create a Flash's Textarea component using AS3's TextField or come close to it?

If not then is there a way to change the individual border colours of the AS3 TextField such as the top, left, right and bottom border colour.

Answer (score 0):

Flash Pro's component source code is available from your install at:

**Mac**:  /Applications/Adobe Flash CS5.5/Common/Configuration/Component Source/ActionScript 3.0/User Interface

**PC**:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\User Interface

Without skinning, a `TextArea` is just a `TextField` with:

```
textField.type = (enabled && _editable) ? TextFieldType.INPUT : TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
textField.selectable = enabled;
textField.wordWrap = _wordWrap;
textField.multiline = true;
```

Upon focus, add a light blue glow filter.

From Flash Pro `fl.controls.TextArea`:

```
// Copyright 2007. Adobe Systems Incorporated. All Rights Reserved.
/**
 * @private (protected)
 *
 * @langversion 3.0
 * @playerversion Flash 9.0.28.0
 */
override protected function configUI():void {
    super.configUI();
    tabChildren = true;

    textField = new TextField();
    addChild(textField);
    updateTextFieldType();

    _verticalScrollBar = new UIScrollBar();
    _verticalScrollBar.name = "V";
    _verticalScrollBar.visible = false;
    _verticalScrollBar.focusEnabled = false;
    copyStylesToChild(_verticalScrollBar, SCROLL_BAR_STYLES);
    _verticalScrollBar.addEventListener(ScrollEvent.SCROLL,handleScroll,false,0,true);
    addChild(_verticalScrollBar);

    _horizontalScrollBar = new UIScrollBar();
    _horizontalScrollBar.name = "H";
    _horizontalScrollBar.visible = false;
    _horizontalScrollBar.focusEnabled = false;
    _horizontalScrollBar.direction = ScrollBarDirection.HORIZONTAL;
    copyStylesToChild(_horizontalScrollBar, SCROLL_BAR_STYLES);
    _horizontalScrollBar.addEventListener(ScrollEvent.SCROLL,handleScroll,false,0,true);
    addChild(_horizontalScrollBar);

    textField.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, handleTextInput, false, 0, true);
    textField.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, handleChange, false, 0, true);
    textField.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyDown, false, 0, true);

    _horizontalScrollBar.scrollTarget = textField;
    _verticalScrollBar.scrollTarget = textField;
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, handleWheel, false, 0, true);
}
```